# shortern code using function in awk

Tags: string, function, replace, awk

My current awk code like this

```
awk -F" " '
function strcleaner(string)
{    
    gsub("oid=","",$string);
    gsub("ver=","",$string);
    gsub("vers=","",$string);
    gsub("type=","",$string);
    gsub(",","",$string);
    return $string;
}
BEGIN   { print "OID\tVersions\tObject Type" } 
    {           
        if ($1 !="Update:") {
            if($1 =="MainFullCourse:") {    
            gsub("oid=","",$2);
            gsub(",","",$2);
            gsub("ver=","",$3);
            gsub("vers=","",$3);
            gsub(",","",$3);
            gsub("type=","",$4);
            gsub(",","",$4);
            print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4
            }               
        }
    }
END     { print " - DONE -" } 
' $detlogfile >> "./final.txt"
```

Currently, I have to clean $2, $3, $4 manually using

```
            gsub("oid=","",$2);
            gsub(",","",$2);
            gsub("ver=","",$3);
            gsub("vers=","",$3);
            gsub(",","",$3);
            gsub("type=","",$4);
            gsub(",","",$4);
```

Is it possible to make a strcleaner function, so I could use

```
print strcleaner($2) "\t" strcleaner($3) "\t" strcleaner($4)
```

Sample input

```
MainFullCourse: oid=13252254, vers=1, type=142, size=186
```

Expected Output

```
13252251 1 142
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: Updated my question and give my input and expect out put

Comment: Hm. The sample input doesn't really seem to match the patterns in the `gsub` calls. There's no `oid=`, `ver=`, `vers=` or `type=` in it anywhere.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Should be "MainFullCourse: oid=13252254, vers=1, type=142, size=186"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're attempting correctly, then

```
awk -F" " '
  function strcleaner(string)
  {    
      # No $s here.
      gsub("oid=","",string);
      gsub("ver=","",string);
      gsub("vers=","",string);
      gsub("type=","",string);
      gsub(",","",string);
      return string;
  }
  BEGIN   { print "OID\tVersions\tObject Type" } 
  $1 == "MainFullCourse:" {           
    print strcleaner($2) "\t" strcleaner($3) "\t" strcleaner($4)
  }               
  END     { print " - DONE -" } 
  ' $detlogfile >> "./final.txt"
```

`$` is not for general variable access in awk (just the variable name suffices), it's to access a certain field. You can say `num = 1`, and then `$num` will be the first field (`$1`).

Comment: The first arg for gsub() is an RE, not a string, so it's misleading at best to use string delimiters, and if you really wanted to remove multiple REs you'd do it with just 1 gsub() not many, e.g. `gsub(/(oid|vers?|type)=|,/,"",string)`. None of that is necessary though and neither is explicitly setting FS to its default value.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this completely wrong. To do what you've told us so far all you need is:

```
$ awk -F'[:,=] *' '{print $3, $5, $7}' file
13252254 1 142
```

and if you want to do something additional, the way you are doing it is wrong too as it's the wrong way to do anything. If you'd like help to do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way, post a new question with additional input/output and description.